# O que é o problema das queries N+1?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, terminologia, desempenho, orm

Sempre que trabalhamos com algum ORM, é comum cair no problema das *queries* N+1. É algo sobre performance, chamado até de *antipattern*.

Mas o que é realmente esse problema, por que ele acontece, quais suas principais causas e como, na teoria, resolvê-los?

Já ouvi também que para resolver, é só praticar o *eager loading*. Mas até que ponto ele é benéfico e capaz de resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você faz uma consulta para pegar uma lista. Então para cada elemento dessa lista, você faz 1 consulta. Ou seja, N+1 consultas. Quando me liberar de umas revisões de merge eu vou atrás de responder, caso não o tenham feito

Comment: O Gavin King, criador do Hibernate disse uma vez no blog que quando ele é contratado p/ fazer consultoria sobre ORM, etc muitas vezes tem que dizer "Neste caso não usamos ORM, use uma query". ORM é ótimo mão não serve p/ resolver 100% dos casos. Era uma vez um relatório que deveria mostrar apenas o total de consultas no mês feitas por uma rede de clínicas. O ORM tinha que carregas as clínias, os médicos, os pacientes, as consultas... acabava tentando carregar todos os registros de todas as tabelas e depois de 20 min dava timeout. Uma query fazia a mesma coisa em uma fração de segundo

Answer (score 25, accepted):

O problema não é exclusivo de ORMs, embora muitos o acham porque é um problema comum, mas não inerente a eles. E talvez não acreditem na capacidade das pessoas fazerem errado manualmente :).

No ORM aparece mais porque uma implementação ingênua forcará o problema ocorrer sempre.

Alias não é um problema só do ORM em si, mas de modelar objetos com dados relacionados. Ou usa um banco de dados com um modelo não relacional, que tem lá seus problemas, ou adota-se o modelo relacional na aplicação.

Ainda assim dá pra fazer criar algum problema quando mistura os dois modelos.

O problema é comum quando tem um objeto e outros N relacionados, daí o nome N + 1 que é o "pai" desses N. O problema fica claro quando a consulta pega o dado principal, vamos dizer que seja uma nota fiscal, e depois vai pegar as linhas de itens que compõe a nota. Ficar indo buscar dados individualmente no banco de dados pode se tornar um custo muito alto, ainda mais na arquitetura mal pensada que muitas pessoas fazem (alguns por necessidade).

Geralmente pelo menos o 1 + 1 é necessário, que é um falha da comunicação dos modelos relacionais (não do modelo, mas sim da forma com eles se comunicam nas implementações atuais, o que considero um erro, e em vez de consertarem isso, criaram outro modelo pior, é a história da nossa área, resolvem um problema com outro problema, mas nada que outro problema não possa resolver este também). Tem como evitar um pouco isso mas com baixa eficiência.

Alias, é por isso mesmo que alguns pessoas gostam de usar um DB NoSQL como *proxy* do relacional. Novamente, aumenta-se a complexidade da solução porque o ferramenta tem problemas fáceis de resolver, mas ninguém o faz.

Mas nesse caso se o tamanho é grande não será um grande problema.

O problema do *eager loading* é que pode trazer informações que sequer vai usar. Mas depende muito do problema, tem casos que isso é raro acontecer, tem outros que mesmo que aconteça não faz nem cócegas, e em muitos casos o fato de vir mais do que precisa gera um *overhead* tão pequeno que uma simples consulta extra já será pior, ou seja um 1 + 2 já pode ser pior. Imagine ler uma única nota fiscal e ele trazer todas as linhas de todas notas fiscais para evitar o N + 1, desperdício total.

Esse é o problema de soluções automatizadas ou de programadores que não entendem o que estão fazendo e adotam soluções de forma automática. A solução real é entender o que ocorrerá naquele caso e decidir o que é mais interessante. Mesmo manualmente é complicado atender todos os casos, depende da consulta. O ORM pode ter um mecanismo que tenta "adivinhar" qual é a melhor estratégia.

Em muitos casos traz-se muita repetição de informação pela maneira como se convencionou trabalhar com dados tabulares, geralmente usa-se o `JOIN`.

Na maioria das vezes trazer tudo de uma vez costuma ser mais interessante que trazer um a um.

Por falta de uma solução melhor seria algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM Nf
SELECT * FROM NfItem
```

Se tiver 1000 notas e em média exatamente 10 itens por nota, haverá 11 mil linhas ao todo, com 2 consultas, uma grande e outra enorme.

Em oposição da forma N+1:

```
SELECT * FROM Nf
SELECT * FROM NfItem WHERE NfNumero == Nf.Numero
SELECT * FROM NfItem WHERE NfNumero == Nf.Numero
SELECT * FROM NfItem WHERE NfNumero == Nf.Numero
SELECT * FROM NfItem WHERE NfNumero == Nf.Numero
.
.
.
Tantos quantos forem a quantidade de notas fiscais existentes.
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/NPlusOne.sql).

Aqui também terá 11 mil linhas, mas com 1000 consultas pequenas e 1 grande.

O código é bem abstrato, só para ilustrar.

Experimente fritar um filete de batata de cada vez e um monte de filete de uma vez. O primeiro método termina rápido individualmente, mas o todo fica trágico. O segundo método demora mais, mas quando terminar está tudo pronto. Só é um problema se descobrir que tinha vendido só 3 filetes, e fritou o pacote inteiro.

Comment: Conheço um sujeito que vende filetes de batata fritados individualmente, em pacotes de 50. Ele circula por aí num Fiat 147.

Comment: @bfavaretto e está certo? Ou só funciona?

Comment: Só funciona. E olhe lá. A maioria das batatas já chega fria na hora de comer.

Comment: Eu já vi frameworks resolvendo assim: `SELECT * FROM table`, `SELECT * FROM related_table WHERE table_id IN(?, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 27):

> Mas o que é realmente esse problema

A melhor forma de explicar este problema é com um exemplo.

Imagine que você tem uma tabela `Pessoa` e uma tabela `Endereco`. Cada pessoa tem vários endereços, consolidando uma relação de **um para muitos** (`1-N`).

E agora você deseja pegar os endereços de várias pessoas. Normalmente, vemos a seguinte consulta utilizando o ORM de sua preferência (vou usar a notação JPQL do JPA):

```
public List<Pessoa> consultarPessoas() {
    String jpql = "select * from Pessoa";
    return em.createQuery(jpql).getResultList();
}
```

E, em seguida, você itera por cada Pessoa para pegar os seus endereços:

```
List<Pessoa> pessoas = consultarPessoas():
for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
    List<Endereco> enderecos = pessoa.getEnderecos();
}
```

Imaginando um `LAZY` entre pessoa e endereços, teremos o seguinte SQL para **cada** pessoa ao chamar o método `pessoa.getEnderecos()`:

```
SELECT * from Endereco where pessoa_id = :id;
```

> , por que ele acontece,

O problema ocorre porque para pegar os endereços das pessoas você pega primeiro a pessoa e depois busca os endereços de cada. Imaginando que a consulta anterior nos retornou 5 pessoas, a quantidade de SQLs gerados será algo assim:

```
 SELECT * from pessoa
 SELECT * from endereco where pessoa_id = 1;
 SELECT * from endereco where pessoa_id = 2;
 SELECT * from endereco where pessoa_id = 3;
 SELECT * from endereco where pessoa_id = 4;
 SELECT * from endereco where pessoa_id = 5;
```

Ou seja, **1** select de pessoa com **N** select para endereços, o famoso **N + 1** .

> quais suas principais causas

Normalmente ela é causada pelo uso inadequado dos ORMs. É preciso entender o que o ORM faz por trás dos bastidores. Embora eles estejam aí para facilitar nossa vida, eles precisam ser usados com sabedoria. Por serem muito permissivos de forma geral, resultados inesperados podem ser causados no mal uso da ferramenta.

> e como, na teoria, resolvê-los?

No exemplo que dei anteriormente, seu objetivo era pegar os endereços de várias pessoas. Se forem os endereços de todas as pessoas do banco de dados, você precisa apenas fazer:

```
 SELECT * from Endereco
```

Mas se quiser aplicar um filtro para trazer aquelas 5 pessoas, isto pode ser feito evitando aquelas várias consultas com um JPQL diferente, partindo da tabela Endereco também:

```
 SELECT * from Endereco where pessoa_id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

> Já ouvi também que para resolver, é só praticar o eager loading. Mas até que ponto ele é benéfico e capaz de resolver esse problema?

O *EAGER loading* é uma alternativa, pois o SQL gerado seria algo assim:

```
select p.id, p.nome, end.id, end.rua, end.pessoa_id from pessoa p JOIN endereco end ON end.pessoa_id = p.id
```

Contudo, o `EAGER` é um problema se adicionado entre o relacionamento de Pessoa e Endereço no seu ORM, pois **toda vez** que você buscar uma pessoa, os endereços também virão juntos. Acredite, você **não quer** isto como comportamento padrão do seu sistema. Os principais problemas de performance que vi em aplicações que envolviam o uso de algum ORM eram causados por isto.

Alguns ORMs tem a alternativa de usar o `FETCH` opcionalmente em uma consulta, assim você pode "ligar" o `EAGER` quando quiser. No JPQL, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * from pessoa JOIN FETCH pessoa.enderecos
```

Resultando no mesmo SQL que citei anteriormente.

Porém, existe uma séria **limitação** com `FETCH` e `EAGER` se você tentar aplicar algum tipo de **paginação** na consulta. Usando `EAGER` ou `FETCH` isto não é possível de ser aplicado no próprio SQL gerado, e para ter uma consulta com este mesmo efeito (trazer pessoas e endereços na mesma consulta) você precisará apelar uma consulta nativa e/ou usar [funções nativas (como o DENSE_RANK)](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-fix-the-hibernate-hhh000104-firstresultmaxresults-specified-with-collection-fetch-applying-in-memory-warning-message/) do banco de dados.

Comment: Excelente explicação.